# How to merging a series with data frame with keeping data from both sides

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

## Python. How to merging a series with data frame with keeping data from both sides

Using concat, it give me all the values from "g_spend" but not from "grouped_cw", leads= NaN

```
t = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(grouped_cw), g_spend], ignore_index=False)

t.head()

output:

 id Campaign_ID_name  Month  Account  campaignid  campaign_name cost  leads
0  35119190 brand    2019|08  SU    35119190  Brand     $59 NaN
```

Using join, it give me all the values from "grouped_cw" but not from "g_spend", leads= NaN  the opposite...

```
t = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(grouped_cw), g_spend], ignore_index=False)

t.head()

output:

    Account Campaign_ID_nameMonthcampaign_namecampaignidcostid  leads
1076533154  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 40.0
143679198   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 58.0
169278078   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 13.0
1729099155  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.0
2016404066  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 6.0
```

## Desired output:

#### It would be okay create a for loop to count "lead" and place in new column in the g_spend dataframe with no (join,merge,concat and etc..)

### Whatever that works!  :)

```
   Campaign_ID_name  Month  Account  campaignid  campaign_name  costh     leads
0    35119190   35119190 brand    2019|08  SU   35119190  Brand     $59    391
```

## Here is the data, Goal is join then by campaignid

g_spend.to_dict()

```
{'id': {0: 35119190,
  1: 64002140,
  2: 272351300,
  3: 4899110,},
 'Campaign_ID_name': {0: 'brand',
  1: '-',
  2: '-',
  3: 'science',
,
 'Month': {0: '2019|08',
  1: '2019|08',
  2: '2019|08',
  3: '2019|08',
},
 'Account': {0: 'a',
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'c',
},
 'campaignid': {0: 35119190,
  1: 64002140,
  2: 272351300,
  3: 4899110,
 },
 'campaign_name': {0: 'All_Brand',
  1: 'All',
  2: 'All_GBHS',
  3: 'All_Science',
},
 'cost': {0: '$59,399.37 ',
  1: '$12,660.37 ',
  2: '$5,631.96 ',
}}
```

grouped_cw.to_dict()

1076533154 is refereed to campaignid
40.0 is the number of leads

```
{'leads': {'1076533154': 40.0,
  '143679198': 58.0,
  '169278078': 13.0,
  '1729099155': 8.0,
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as seen from the `to_dict()` commands, is that `g_spend.campaignid` are numeric, while `grouped_cw.index` are string. You can, for example, convert `g_spend.campaignid` to string and merge:

```
g_spend.campaignid = g_spend.campaignid.astype(str)

g_spend.merge(grouped_cw, left_on='campaignid', right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge()` for this purpose:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(grouped_cw), g_spend, on="campaignid", how='outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

g_spend.campaignid = g_spend.campaignid.astype(str)

g_spend.merge(grouped_cw, left_on='campaignid', right_index=True)